# No known Consul servers

Tags: consul, envoyproxy, servicemesh

I have 3 nodes Consul cluster deployed in AWS ECS. If the nodes goes down one by one. The 3 new nodes will come up, but the services which were connected previously using load balancer url are not able to connect again with the consul the logs shows "No known Consul servers" error.

Ideally the services should be able to connect is there something missing or a workaround to it? else this could result in a major outage.